# Best way to preserve new lines when I post data from a Multi Line Text Field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multiline

What is the best way to preserve new break lines when I post data from a Multi Line Text Field

I am working on ReacJS so

```
    <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            multiline
            fullWidth
            name={"Description"}
            margin="normal"
            placeholder="Describe tu proyecto aqui..."
            onChange={handleupdateField}
            value={formPublishProject.Description}
            rows={4}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </Grid>
```

And I preserve the value in the state

```
  const handleupdateField = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...formPublishProject,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
```

I would like keep text same as it was typed

[image: Multi Line Text Field]

But when I submit this input in the console log show description string like that "Hello,↵↵-This is the new line↵↵↵", If I save this text in the database when I will get this values it will shows enter symbol (↵) and I want to show multiline text same as it was typed.

[image: ConsoleLog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this, is you can replace the carriage return symbol with a newline

```
state = {
    description: `Hello,↵↵-This is the new line↵↵↵` // some example string coming from the database
};

<TextField
    multiline
    value={this.state.description.replace(/↵/g, "\n")}
    ...
/>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-bartik-2rokv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, it works, I'll save in the database the carriage return symbol in description text and I'll show description text using .replace(/↵/g, "\n"), thanks!!

Comment: Other solution   <Typography
                style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}
                variant="body2"
                color="textSecondary"
                component="span"
              >
                {project.description}
              </Typography>