# MUI How to output text with Break Lines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

Every time I add content to the MUI Textfield it outputs it without any line breaks.

Is there a better solution to use?

```
<Stack direction="row" alignItems="start" justifyContent="start" mb={5}>
      <TextField 
          name="Content" placeholder="Content" multiline={true}
          value={content}
          rows={18}
          sx={{width: '100%'}}
          onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
          />
     <div style={{maxWidth:"50%", paddingLeft:"10px"}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: generateContent(content)}}></div>
</Stack>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dewdney-crxls

```js
<Stack direction="row">
  <TextField multiline value={state} onChange={handleChange} />
  <Box sx={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{state}</Box>
</Stack>
```

I used the `whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"` sx prop on the box where I am previewing the text, and I used the `multiline` prop on the textfield to make it a textarea input, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your CSS and not in MUI. Use the `white-space` CSS property like this:

```
<div style={{maxWidth:"50%", paddingLeft:"10px", whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}}...
```

[Read more about `pre-wrap` and the other values here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#pre-wrap)

*If this does not work then there are two similar questions but I doubt you will need them.*

- [Best way to preserve new lines when I post data from a Multi Line Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432824/best-way-to-preserve-new-lines-when-i-post-data-from-a-multi-line-text-field)
- [New line '\n' not recognized inside TextField in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177549/new-line-n-not-recognized-inside-textfield-in-react)